# Quadrangle ABCD that is not a parallelogram, but does have a parallel side

Tags: geometry

Does there exist a quadrangle ABCD that is not a parallelogram, but AB is parallel to CD?

Comment: Have you tried to draw such a quadrangle ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. In general, those things are called [trapesoids](https://tl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trapesoid).

Answer (score 1):

If a quadrilateral has two sides that are parallel **and** have equal length, then it is a parallelogram.